# Get posts in custom post type categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have a custom post type defined like so with taxonomies are standard categories:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Works', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Work', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Works', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Works', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Work', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Work Description', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'show_in_rest' => true,
);
register_post_type( 'works', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

I am trying to list all posts within the post type category. So for example I have illustration as a category so all posts with illustration.

```
<?php
if(is_category()){
    //get the category
    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID; 

    //list all posts by category
    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'Works', // the post type
       //not sure how to add category id.
    );
// The query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<h2> List of posts tagged with this tag </h2>';

    echo '<ul>';
    $html_list_items = '';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $html_list_items .= '<li>';
        $html_list_items .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        $html_list_items .= get_the_title();
        $html_list_items .= '</a>';
        $html_list_items .= '</li>';
    }
    echo $html_list_items;
    echo '</ul>';

} else {
    // no posts found
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of [**Category Parameters**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters) for your [**WP_Query**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

- `cat` (`int`) – use category id.
- `category_name` (`string`) – use category slug.
- `category__and` (`array`) – use category id.
- `category__in` (`array`) – use category id.
- `category__not_in` (`array`) – use category id.

  ```
  //list all posts by category
  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'works', // NOT 'Works'
      // Add category id like this.
     'cat' => $cat_id
      );
  ```

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something as simple as that.